# Proving $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$ for convergent $\{x_n\}_{n≥0}\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Assuming that for $\{x_n\}_{n≥0}\subset\mathbb{R}$ we have $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ I want to show that $x=\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Is the following proof correct?

Let $M_n=\{x_k\mid k≥n\}$ and $s_n=\sup M_n$, so $s:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. So
$$
\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n≥N\ :\ |x-x_n|≤\varepsilon\iff\\
\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n≥N\ :\ x-\varepsilon≤x_n≤x+\varepsilon
$$
So $M_n$ is bounded above by $x+\varepsilon$ for all $n≥N$ and therefore $s_n≤x+\varepsilon\ \forall n≥N$. But also $x_n\in M_n$ and thus $s_n≥x_n≥x-\varepsilon\ \forall n≥N$. Hence we have:
$$
\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n≥N\ :\ |s_n-x|≤\varepsilon\implies\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=x
$$
And similarly for $\liminf$.

Is everything alright like that?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything until "Hence we have..." You showed that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|s_n-x| \leq \epsilon$ (not $|s-x_n| \leq \epsilon$). You do make the correct conclusion, however, that this implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n=x$, so I suspect that's just a typo.

Comment: Yes this was a typo, I corrected it now :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same objection as kccu (withdrawn now after your edit).

Alternative:

Analogously let $t_{n}:=\inf M_n $ and $t:=\lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n}=\liminf x_{n}$.

Then evidently $t_{n}\leq s_{n}$ for each $n$ so that $t\leq s$.

For every $r>x$ some $n$ exists with $k\geq n\implies x_{k}\leq r$.

So $s\leq s_{n}\leq r$ for *every* $r>x$ and consequently $s\leq x$.

Likewise it can be shown that $t\geq x$.

So we have $x\leq t\leq s\leq x$ or equivalently $t=x=s$.